# Azure Devops run time parameters passing values

Tags: azure-devops

I have the following code and it is working properly when it is triggered manually. But, the pipeline is failing during automatic trigger (like pushing the code from vscode). How to handle this situation? Thanks!

```
parameters:
  - name: terraformAction
    displayName: Apply/Destroy
    values:
      - Apply
      - Destroy

stages:
  - stage: TERRAFORM_APPLY
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.terraformAction }}', 'Apply')
    jobs:
      - job: 
        steps:
        - script: |
           echo "The Selected Action is ${{ parameters.terraformAction }} "

  - stage: TERRAFORM_DESTROY
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.terraformAction }}', 'Destroy')
    jobs:
      - job: 
        steps:
        - script: |
           echo "The Selected Action is ${{ parameters.terraformAction }} "
```

The error is: "A value for the 'terraformAction' parameter must be provided."

Comment: **How** is it failing? Are you getting an error message? If so, post the error message.

Comment: @DanielMann- Thanks for highlighting, I have updated the error at the end of the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your parameter doesn't have a `default` provided. When you run it manually, you must select one of the two values from the dropdown. When it triggers otherwise, the value is blank. The error message is telling you that.

Comment: How to pass the value.. apply or destroy during automatic trigger?

Comment: You don't. It will always use the default, or be blank if a default isn't specified. If there are other conditions that can be used to infer whether to apply or destroy (such as a commit message), then you can write conditional logic to evaluate and choose an action.

Comment: Thank You! The work around is to have a proper commit message in this case.